# Is a content on a ring $\emptyset$-continuous iff it is upper semicontinuous?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In the first chapter of Achim Klenke's book on Probability Theory, he first gives the definition of $\emptyset$-continuous content and upper semicontinuous content. Both are defined on a ring (instead of a semiring).

However, right after the definition, there is a theorem in which he says that the two are equivalent (for every content on a ring). My question is, if they are equivalent then why do we have two different definitions that are already similar? I did not understand the proof of that as well where he says that it is evident that every upper semicontinuous content on a ring is $\emptyset$-continuous. Am I missing something in the definitions?

Definitions:
A content $\mu$ on a ring $\mathscr{A}$ is

1. Upper semicontinuous if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(A)$$
   for any $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$ and any sequence $\{A_n\}$ in $\mathscr{A}$ s.t. $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for eventually all $n$ and $A_n$ decreases to $A$.
2. $\emptyset$-continuous if the above definition holds for $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: What are the definitions?

Comment: @DanielHast I have added the definitions in the description of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If they are equivalent then why do we have two different definitions that are already similar?

I don't think there is any reason more than to show that these two properties, which seem similar but are slightly different, are in fact equivalent.

> I did not understand the proof of that as well where he says that it is evident that every $\emptyset$-continuous content on a ring is upper semicontinuous.

Suppose you have $A,A_1,A_2,\ldots \in \mathcal{A}$ with $A_n \downarrow A$ and $\mu(A_1) < \infty$. Defining $B_n = A_n \setminus A$, we have $B_n \downarrow \emptyset$. Using $\emptyset$-continuity,

$$0 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(B_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) - \mu(A),$$

showing upper semicontinuity.

Comment: (1) Since we don't know if the content is monotone, shouldn't it be $\mu (A_i)$ is finite for eventually all $i$?

(2) In this proof, you are only showing that only for a certain class of sequence of sets that decrease to a set, $\mu$ is upper semicontinuous, while the definition says that it is true for any such sequence.

Comment: @AksharaPrasad (1) Yes. If I instead have $\mu(A_i) < \infty$ for all $i \geq N$ for some $N$, then I can just consider the sequence $A_N, A_{N+1}, \ldots$, which _does_ satisfy my condition. (2) I am not sure what you mean. I am considering an arbitrary set $A$ together with an arbitrary sequence of sets of finite measure that decreases to it, is that not all that is there in the definition?

Comment: right, thank you. The author says that the other direction of the theorem is evident. Is this because every $\emptyset$-continuous content is upper semicontinuous by definition?

Comment: @AksharaPrasad No, every upper semicontinuous content is $\emptyset$-continuous by definition. The other direction follows from what I have written in the second half of the answer. "Evident" is a subjective word, I don't think it follows directly from the definition itself.